# Which episode features Natsu joining Fairy Tail and Erza teaching him to write?

Tags: fairy-tail

I know there was one episode where it says how Natsu joined Fairy Tail and then he found some mission and Erza started teaching him reading and writing, but I forgot which one it was....

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to `Episode 27`. Also note that that was an anime only scene, and you aren't quite remembering it right. Natsu already knew how to read thanks to Igneel. Erza just expanded his vocabulary.